# TextBox MaxLength property is counting whitespace

Tags: wpf, textbox, whitespace, maxlength

My TextBox has a limit of 100 characters set by MaxLength property.

However, if the user types '\n' or '\t', they are counted as an additional character, which would make sense to the programmer, but not to the user.

Is there any workaround besides counting the characters by myself?

Comment: Why you just add a textchangedEvent an there you cout your text length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own attached property:

```
<TextBox wpfApplication4:TextBoxBehaviors.MaxLengthIgnoringWhitespace="10" />
```

With the attached property defined like this:

```
    public static class TextBoxBehaviors
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxLengthIgnoringWhitespaceProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "MaxLengthIgnoringWhitespace",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(TextBoxBehaviors),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(int), MaxLengthIgnoringWhitespaceChanged));

    private static void MaxLengthIgnoringWhitespaceChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var textBox = dependencyObject as TextBox;

        if (textBox != null && eventArgs.NewValue is int)
        {
            textBox.TextChanged += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    var maxLength = ((int)eventArgs.NewValue) + textBox.Text.Count(char.IsWhiteSpace);
                    textBox.MaxLength = maxLength;  
                };
        }
    }

    public static void SetMaxLengthIgnoringWhitespace(DependencyObject element, int value)
    {
        element.SetValue(MaxLengthIgnoringWhitespaceProperty, value);
    }

    public static int GetMaxLengthIgnoringWhitespace(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (int)element.GetValue(MaxLengthIgnoringWhitespaceProperty);
    }
}
```

The code will use the TextBox's existing MaxLength property and will just increase it by the number of white spaces you have entered.  So if you set the property to 10 and type in 5 spaces, the actual MaxLength on the TextBox will be set to 15, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I really enjoy `Toby Crawford`answer but since i started to try a simple answer i like to add mine :

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string TextLength { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void txtInput_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textbox = sender as TextBox;
            var tempText = textbox.Text.Replace(" ", "");
            lblLength.Content = (tempText.Length).ToString();
        }
    }
       <Grid>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="txtInput" MaxLength="{Binding TextMaxLength}" Height="23" Margin="220,67,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" TextChanged="txtInput_TextChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
            <Label Name="lblLength"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="220,126,0,0"/>
            <Label Content="Your text length" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="93,126,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Label Content="Your text" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="93,67,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

        </Grid>
```

[image]